# Pass Object from LoginComponent to ProfilComponent

Tags: angular, typescript

I start with angular my question is how to pass an object (connectedUser) from LoginComponent to ProfilComponenet

thank you in advance

Comment: There are lot of ways to do this using `@input` using `shared service`, just google it you will get lot of ways.

Answer (score 0):

Try like that :

```
export Class LoginComponent {
myobject = {}

}
```

in the template :

```
<app-profile-component [data]="myobject"></app-profile-component>
```

in the app profile Component :

```
export class ProfileComponent {
@input() data : any; // Object is Recived here 

}
```

Comment: this method works if we have a parent and son component but this is not the case

Comment: so you can store objects in the service file and fetch in the Profile Component.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of several ways to implement it. First, I create a service name AppStateService (app-state.service.ts) to hold and shared an object. I hope this may help you.

app-state.service.ts file:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AppStateService {
  private _connectedUser: any = undefined;

  public get connectedUser(): any {
    return this._connectedUser;
  }
  public set connectedUser(value: any) {
    this._connectedUser = value;
  }
}
```

login.component.ts file:

```
constructor(private appState: AppStateService) { }

public onLoggedin(): void {
  this.authService.login(username, password).subscribe(res => {
    this.appState.connectedUser = res.data;
  });
}
```

profile.component.ts file:

```
public connectedUser;

constructor(private appState: AppStateService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.connectedUser = this.appState.connectedUser;
  console.log('I:--START--:--ProfileComponent OnLoad--:connectedUser/', connectedUser);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried this method but the object connected remains empty: undefined in the Profile component

Comment: You need to register AppStateService class into app.module.ts. To shared objects between components, the service must be a singleton service, in which only one instance exists in angular project.